# Column wise correspondence values in data frame

Tags: python, r, data-science

Given a dataframe, with Age as basis, I need to get the correspondence values from other columns (Sport, Mode). Could someone help with R/python code?
 
[image: test data set]. 
In fact, it will be helpful if I could get for age 15, 2 baseball with 2 play; age 19 1 golf and 1 play.

the output should look like the below with Age as base variable
[image]

Further on with Sport as base variable, the mode should have a similar summary. Thank you

Comment: Can you please make your example reproducible and show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Looks like you want to count the values of each column. It's important to show us how you want your output to  be, as it can have different formats.

Comment: Still not sure if you want one output or 2 outputs (one for Sports and one for Mode), but will post something that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = data.frame(Age = c(15,15,16,17,18,18,19,20),
                Sport = c("Baseball","Baseball","Baseball","Baseball","Baseball","Golf","Golf","Golf"),
                Mode = c("Play","Play","Play","Watch","Watch","Play","Play","Watch"),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  count(Age, Sport) %>%
  spread(Sport, n, fill = 0)

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#     Age Baseball  Golf
# * <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    15        2     0
# 2    16        1     0
# 3    17        1     0
# 4    18        1     1
# 5    19        0     1
# 6    20        0     1


df %>%
  count(Age, Mode) %>%
  spread(Mode, n, fill = 0)

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#     Age  Play Watch
# * <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    15     2     0
# 2    16     1     0
# 3    17     0     1
# 4    18     1     1
# 5    19     1     0
# 6    20     0     1
```

If you want to produce a single output you can use this:

```
df = data.frame(Age = c(15,15,16,17,18,18,19,20),
                Sport = c("Baseball","Baseball","Baseball","Baseball","Baseball","Golf","Golf","Golf"),
                Mode = c("Play","Play","Play","Watch","Watch","Play","Play","Watch"),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# function that reshapes data based on a column name
# (uses Age column as an identifier/key)
f = function(x) {
df %>%
  group_by_("Age",x) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  spread_(x, "n", fill = 0) %>%
  ungroup()
}


names(df)[names(df) != "Age"] %>%   # get all column names (different than Age)
  map(f) %>%                        # apply function to each column name
  reduce(left_join, by="Age")       # join datasets sequentially

# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#     Age Baseball  Golf  Play Watch
#   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    15        2     0     2     0
# 2    16        1     0     1     0
# 3    17        1     0     0     1
# 4    18        1     1     1     1
# 5    19        0     1     1     0
# 6    20        0     1     0     1
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Worked like charm.